# Views aren't redrawing after changes

Tags: android, view, android-softkeyboard, android-drawable, android-handler

On a Huawei phone running 4.0.1 I have a problem with views redrawing.  In one situation I show the keyboard when the user is performing the search feature but when they hide the keyboard the views aren't redrawn that were behind the keyboard.  The screen is just left blank in that space.

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post( new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
  }
});
```

I have other situations where I see simular symptoms with or without the post method but this was the simplest case to show.  How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Hey! Have you found any solution to this?  I'm seeing exactly same behaviour on LG L5 with CyanogenMod 4.0.3

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't.  I'm glad to know I'm not the only person that has seen something like this though.